# Can the internal angles of a triangle ever add up to 360 degrees, or more?

Tags: geometry, triangles

On flat 2d paper, a triangle's internal angles add up to 180 degrees. Drawn on the side of a 3d soccer ball, they add up to 270 degrees.

Can they ever add up to 360 degrees (or even more) as the number of dimensions of the thing that the triangle is drawn on increases beyond 3?

Comment: Number of dimensions is irrelevant, since a triangle will be contained in a 2-dimenisional affine subspace.  Try using a triangle on a sphere (the sides are great circles).  Perhaps, in a spherical triangle, the "inside" can be considered the "outside" of the triangle?

Comment: @GEdgar How can the no. of dimensions be irrelevant as clearly the summation goes from 180 to 270 by adding another dimension?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Irrespective of the number of sides, *in a spherical triangle,* we can choose any angle at a vertex. For example when angles situation at one vertex of equilateral spherical triangles:

In an equilateral point triangle (almost flat) with three vanishing sides the sum of three internal angles tends to $3\times 60^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$ in green and,

for the remaining largest spherical triangle (almost sphere) the sum of three internal angles tends to $3\times 300^{\circ}=900^{\circ}$ in yellow.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, an error at the (almost)  sphere  vertex corrected.

Comment: Thanks for having the respect & decency to answer. Unlike those others...